# Why does Dask read parquet file in a lot slower than Pandas reading same parquet file?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, parquet

I am testing read speads on parquet files using Dask and python and I'm finding that reading the same file with pandas is significantly faster than Dask. I am looking to understand why this is and if there is a way to get equal performance,

versions all the relevant packages

`print(dask.__version__)
 print(pd.__version__)
 print(pyarrow.__version__)
 print(fastparquet.__version__)`

`2.6.0
 0.25.2
 0.15.1
 0.3.2`

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd

col = [str(i) for i in list(np.arange(40))]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5000000, 4 * 10)), columns=col)

df.to_parquet('large1.parquet', engine='pyarrow')
 # Wall time: 3.86 s
df.to_parquet('large2.parquet', engine='fastparquet')
 # Wall time: 27.1 s
df = dd.read_parquet('large2.parquet', engine='fastparquet').compute()
 # Wall time: 5.89 s
df = dd.read_parquet('large1.parquet', engine='pyarrow').compute()
 # Wall time: 4.84 s
df = pd.read_parquet('large1.parquet',engine='pyarrow')
 # Wall time: 503 ms 
df = pd.read_parquet('large2.parquet',engine='fastparquet')
 # Wall time: 4.12 s
```

When working with a mixed datatypes dataframe the discrepancy is larger.

```
dtypes: category(7), datetime64[ns](2), float64(1), int64(1), object(9)
memory usage: 973.2+ MB
# df.shape == (8575745, 20)
```

```
df.to_parquet('large1.parquet', engine='pyarrow')
 # Wall time: 9.67 s

df.to_parquet('large2.parquet', engine='fastparquet')
 # Wall time: 33.3 s

# read with Dask
df = dd.read_parquet('large1.parquet', engine='pyarrow').compute()
 # Wall time: 34.5 s

df = dd.read_parquet('large2.parquet', engine='fastparquet').compute()
 # Wall time: 1min 22s

# read with pandas 
df = pd.read_parquet('large1.parquet',engine='pyarrow')
 # Wall time: 8.67 s

df = pd.read_parquet('large2.parquet',engine='fastparquet')
 # Wall time: 21.8 s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that Pandas saves Parquet datasets into a single row group, which won't allow a system like Dask to parallelize.  That doesn't explain why it's slower, but it does explain why it isn't faster.

For further information I would recommend profiling.  You may be interested in this document:

- https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/understanding-performance.html